# How to delete dead code or code of no use based on configure file/makefile file

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, static-analysis

When we compile a C/C++ project, some files and codes in the project source are not needed for compilation. For example, test folder (some testing scripts), examples folder and dead code. How can I recognize these source files that are not compiled to binary files? It is not hoped that compiling is necessary. Cause I need to process many projects automatically and it is really hard to compile all projects without manual operations.

I know compilation can delete dead code automatically, but in my situation I can not compile the whole project, and in the source, there are many other codes that are not involved in final compilation such as code in test folder, tools folder... I hope to detect these code, as for dead code, I know its hard to detect it by  static analysis, so disregard it, just care about whole files and whole folders that are not compiled.

Why I want to do this?
I want to extract some features (strings, function call graph, int constants... ) to represent this project and compare this features with the same features extracted from binary files to see what differences are there. So, if I extract features from code in test folder and the code are not compiled in the final binary files. There will be a big error when comparing these features.

Comment: Since you've tagged `cmake` there a simple solution: Multiple targets. One target for the main executable program, and another target for the program to run the tests. The main executable target will of course not have any test sources included.

Comment: Explain: why you need to delete dead code? It might be impossible in general ! What happens to you if some dead code remains? So please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52351969/edit) your question**. You should add several more paragraphs in it (with motivation and context) and show some [MCVE]

Comment: It is not clear what kind of problem you are actually trying to solve here. Files that are not needed for compilation should not be listed for compilation by the developer of that project so there is no need to recognize those files manually. Or are you in situation where you only have .h and .cpp files and need to figure out how to build them? In this case there isn't any simple method to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Dead code would often -but not always- be eliminated by the compiler, when you ask it to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (but **removing *all* dead code automatically is impossible**, since [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) because of equivalence with the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)). Be aware of the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) permitting the compiler to do such optimizations. So in practice you don't need to remove the corresponding source code.

Some industries have as a coding rule (e.g. in [DO-178C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C)) the requirement that dead source code is forbidden. Detecting that is extremely difficult and in general impossible (see e.g. [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)), so requires a lot of sophisticated [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) techniques and external [code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) and costs a big lot (e.g. increase the cost of software development by more than 30x).

Your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) system (e.g. cmake or Makefile, etc...) might be (and usually is) [Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness); so even removing entirely useless C++ source files is an impossible task in general. Even the POSIX shell (used in commands to build your thing) is difficult to analyze (see the excellent [*Parsing Posix [S]hell*](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/code_parsing_posix_s_hell/) talk by Yann Regis-Gianas at FOSDEM2018).

Comment: Dead code in DO178 is defined as code that doesn’t meet any top level (system) requirement (TLR) or any derived requirements. Analysis need not identify/remove dead code since it can – practically usually does – work the opposite direction: start with TLRs and derived requirements, find code needed to meet those requirements. Code reached by such analysis is, by definition, alive - and dead code is excluded simply by not being reached.That's a over-simplistic description, but the point is there is no need to analyse source code to mark it dead in order to exclude it.